# Integration PHP PEAR MAIL in codeigniter

Tags: php, email, class, codeigniter, pear

I've set up successfully the pear integration in codeigniter following the tutorial here:

> http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PEAR_integration/

I would like to use the package Mail:

> http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

I've install it in system/application/pear with all dependences (Net/SMTP, Net/Socket, Auth/SASL)

When I call it ($this->pearloader->load('Mail','mail');) I got the following error:

> Fatal error:
>   Pearloader::require_once()
>   [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'Mail/mail.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/mywebsite/system/application/pear/')
>   in
>   /var/www/mywebsite/system/application/libraries/Pearloader.php
>   on line 6

The Mail/mail.php is in fact in Mail/Mail/mail.php in the package Mail from PEAR.
If I put the mail.php in the upper folder or if I change the pearloader.php to include the path I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in
>   /var/www/mywebsite/system/application/pear/Mail/mail.php
>   on line 51

If I add include_once("Mail.php"); in the mail.php (that I let in the correct path like I said before) it solve the problem but it doesn't sound to me a proper solution.

I don't manage to figure out how I could solve it in "an elegant way". Like I could like to don't have to touch file from the PEAR packages and I want to use pear inside my application.

Is there any geek out there :) who already had this problem and found the a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a codeigniter expert but looking at the errors, " Failed opening" seems like a file permission problem. Check if the permissions are set correct for the file. (I faced a similar problem while using Zend fwk and the file permissions were the problem.)

Comment: I've "re-check" the permissions and they are fine. Anyway the point that when put the mail.php in the upper folder or if I change the pearloader.php to include the path I got other error and when I had the include then it works doesn't seems to me a permissions problem.